# Target individual element mentioned in conditional statement jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to target the actual element mentioned in my conditional statement, here is an example of my code:

```
  let selectValue = $('.Select input').val();
  if ($('.vehicle-item').attr('data-value') != selectValue) {
    //Add a class to the element that hasn't got an attribute equal to the `selectValue` variable.
  }
```

So basically on my page there are multiple elements with the class of `.vehicle-item`some of these will pass the conditional statement and some wont. I would like to add a class to all of the elements with that class that don't pass the conditional statement.

If I could somehow iterate over that conditional statement for every element that didn't pass and add a class that would work however how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to achieve this:

```
let selectValue = $('.Select input').val();
$('.vehicle-item').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('value') != selectValue;
}).addClass('foo');
```

Alternatively you could use the attribute selector:

```
let selectValue = $('.Select input').val();
$('.vehicle-item[data-value!="' + selectValue + '"]').addClass('foo');
```

Note that the latter reads the data attribute directly from the element, so if you update the value programmatically after the page has loaded you will *have* to use `filter()`.

Personally I would use `filter()` anyway as it's slightly faster in most browsers and I find it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that directly using "not equal" selector and multiple selector feature.

```
$(".vehicle-item[data-value!='"+selectValue+"']").each(function(){
        // do something
});
```